# Why can I not JSONSerialize this NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to JSONSerialize an NSArray that I get from an NSFetchRequest, but when I call isValidJSONObject I end up in the section where it tells me it is not valid

The code is as follows and I end up in the "Does not work" part in the debug.

```
+ (int) synchOrder:(NSString *)orderNumber {
    if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
        NSLog(@"WebServices:synchOrder:ordernumber = %@", orderNumber);
    }

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;

    // *** Fetch the orderHead information

    // *** The query for all tables uses orderNumber as selection so we set that up first for re use
    NSPredicate *predicateOrderNumber =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"orderNumber like[cd] %@", [NWTillHelper getCurrentOrderNumber]];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestOh = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"OrderHead"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestOrp = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"OrderRow"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestTender = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Tender"];

    fetchRequestOh.predicate = predicateOrderNumber;
    fetchRequestOrp.predicate = predicateOrderNumber;
    fetchRequestTender.predicate = predicateOrderNumber;

    fetchRequestOh.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    fetchRequestOrp.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    fetchRequestTender.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    NSError *errorOh = nil;
    NSArray *orderHeads = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestOh error:&errorOh] mutableCopy];

    NSError *errorOrp = nil;
    NSArray *orderRows = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestOrp error:&errorOrp] mutableCopy];

    NSError *errorTender = nil;
    NSArray *tenderRows = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestTender error:&errorTender] mutableCopy];

    if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
        NSLog(@"WebServices:synchOrder:orderHeadsArray: %@", orderHeads);
        NSLog(@"WebServices:synchOrder:orderRowsArray: %@", orderRows);
        NSLog(@"WebServices:synchOrder:tenderRowsArray: %@", tenderRows);
    }

    // *** first lets upload orderHead
    NSError *errorWebSvsOhApi;

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSURLSession *sessionOrderHead = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://XXX.YYY.ZZ:0000/path/to/api"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *requestOrderHeads = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

    if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:orderHeads]) {
NSLog(@"works");
} else {
NSLog(@"Does not work");
}
```

The debug output of the array looks as follows.

```
2016-12-24 11:55:38.362 NWMobileTill[1007:69570] WebServices:synchOrder:orderHeadsArray: (
        {
        amountTax = 0;
        companyId = Kalle;
        createdDateUtc = "2016-12-24 03:55:25 +0000";
        isSynched = 0;
        orderNumber = "1-20161224115525";
        orderType = 0;
        status = 0;
        sumAfterTrDiscount = 0;
        sumBeforeTrDiscount = 0;
        tillId = 1;
        trDiscountAmount = 0;
        trDiscountPercentage = 0;
        userName = 1;
    }
)
```

Comment: Custom objects are not valid JSON data. Read the documentation for `NSJSONSerialization` for a description of valid JSON data.

Comment: The issue is most likely the `NSDate` value in the dictionary which is not JSON compliant.

Comment: Yes it was the date format once I got that sorted properly it all works

Answer (score 0):

it has to be work. this is my experiment from your own data and code. it is working fine as you expected.

```
NSArray *test = @[@{@"amountTax" : @0,
                    @"companyId" : @"Kalle",
                    @"createdDateUtc" : @"2016-12-24 03:55:25 +0000",
                    @"isSynched" : @(false),
                    @"orderNumber" : @"1-20161224115525",
                    @"orderType" : @0,
                    @"status" : @(false),
                    @"sumAfterTrDiscount" : @0,
                    @"sumBeforeTrDiscount" : @0,
                    @"tillId" : @1,
                    @"trDiscountAmount" : @0,
                    @"trDiscountPercentage" : @0,
                    @"userName" : @1
                    }];

NSLog(@"Test:%@", test);

if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:test]) {
    NSLog(@"works");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Does not work");
}
```

debug output:

```
Test:(
    {
    amountTax = 0;
    companyId = Kalle;
    createdDateUtc = "2016-12-24 03:55:25 +0000";
    isSynched = 0;
    orderNumber = "1-20161224115525";
    orderType = 0;
    status = 0;
    sumAfterTrDiscount = 0;
    sumBeforeTrDiscount = 0;
    tillId = 1;
    trDiscountAmount = 0;
    trDiscountPercentage = 0;
    userName = 1;
}
)
2016-12-24 13:38:34.098 sample[2628:58572] works
```

**isValidJSONObject** is used to returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object can be converted to JSON data. If you are checking with invalid NSArray object, it will return false. But, as per your code and customised my own array returned valid. Check with your array objects are proper or not and also check whether that array is empty or not. If array is empty, it will return as false.

Comment: likely because you wrote the NSDate as a NSString !?

Comment: so this isn't the same and you give no answer ;)

Comment: that's true now :( I didn't check with that date for this data!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the NSDate cannot be serialised as Vadian stated in the comment, by using the following date formatter it resolved the problem and the NSArray can be JSONSerialized properly

Create the date as follows and setup the dateFormatter

```
NSDate *createdDate = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterWithTz = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterWithTz setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
```

Then when saving the date to persistent storage use the formatter as follows

```
[newTenderRow setValue:[dateFormatterWithTz stringFromDate:createdDate] forKey:@"createdDate"];
```